# Euclidean Homography optimization python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, optimization, scipy

I am working on panoramic stitching. I am trying to refine the euclidian homography matrix estimate which I get after performing RANSAC on the matches, using Levenberg-Marquardt algorithm in `scipy.optimize.least_squares`.
I am doing this to solve for bending in my panoramic image output.

The optimization problem now becomes a nonlinear local optimization, where I minimize homography error function                     : [image]

where x' is transformed point and x is original point.

I am using the `scipy.optimize.least_squares` function as

```
ls_lm = least_squares(fun, [theta, tx, ty], args=(dst,src), method='lm')
```

Where `dst` and `src` are my correspondences from source and destination image after RANSAC. I take `theta, tx, ty` from the homography estimate `H`. My `fun` looks like :

```
def fun(pars, x, src):
    theta, tx, ty = pars
    H = array([[cos(theta), -sin(theta), tx],\
         [sin(theta), cos(theta), ty],
         [0,0,1]])
    src1 = c_[src,ones(src.shape[0])]
    fun = sum((x - src1.dot(H.T)[:,:2])**2)
    ret_val = ones(len(src), float)
    for i in range(len(src)):
        ret_val[i] = fun
    return ret_val
```

But the `least_squares` function is not converging and gives me the same input `[theta, tx, ty]` as output. What am I doing wrong ? Can I solve for the bending problem using some other method or approach ? Can bundle adjustment solve this, if yes how do I implement it ?

Also, is the Jacobian matrix input mandatory for my case ? If yes what should it be ?

Thanks, for your time !!

**Things I tried :**

1) Initialize my parameters from `[0, 0, 0]` and added noise to `H`. Results seem little off to the original H, but don't solve the problem.

2) Use `scipy.optimize.minimize`, got the same results as input.

Comment: `lm` requires the residual for each point, not the summation. Try returning `return np.sum((x - src1.dot(H.T)[:,:2])**2, axis=1)`. The Jacobian is computed numerically using finite differences. As the eqation is known, you can provide manually the jacobian for $$(\mathbf{x}^{`} - \mathbf{H}\mathbf{x})^{2}$$

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried doing this it works but the results seem off. Any idea why ? Would you suggest any other way to solve the problem ?